# What is the replacement for these deprecated methods, in Sonar Java API 5.6?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube5.6

There are some methods in my application using Sonar Java API 4.2. But, I have upgraded to 5.6.1 and unable to implement the replacements for these methods.

- `org.sonar.api.resources.Project.path();`
  I tried using `SensorContext.fileSystem().baseDir().toString()` as a replacement. is the functionality same?
- In `org.sonar.api.batch.Sensor.analyse(Project project,SensorContext context)`, Project and SensorContext have been deprecated and I am looking at only 2 new methods in the new `Sensor` interface which are `describe(SensorDescriptor descriptor)` and `execute(SensorContext context)`. How do I input the Project path as previously?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: with a plugin on client side (implements PostJob) you can access the PostJobContext, with it you have tons of project properties, have you checked it ?